# retaining text after delimiter in fasta headers using awk

Tags: bash, awk, fasta

I have what should be a simple problem, but my lack of awk knowledge is holding me back.

I would like to clean up the headers of a fasta file that is in this format:

```
>HWGG454_Clocus2_Locus3443_allele1
ATTCTACTACTACTCT
>GHW757_clocus37_Locus555662_allele2
CTTCCCTACGATG
>TY45_clocus23_Locus800_allele0
TTCTACTTCATCT
```

I would like to clean up each header (line starting with ">") to retain only the informative part, which is the second  "_Locus*" with or without the allele part.

I thought awk would be the easy way to do this, but I cant quite get it to work.

If I wanted to retain just the first column of text up to the "_" delimiter for the header, and the sequences below, I run this (assuming this toy example is in the file test.fasta):

```
 cat test.fasta | awk -F '_' '{print $1}'

>HWGG454
ATTCTACTACTACTCT
>GHW757
CTTCCCTACGATG
>TY45
TTCTACTTCATCT
```

But, what I want is to retain just the "Locus*" text, which is after the 3rd delimiter, but, using this code I get this:

```
cat test.fasta | awk -F '_' '{print $3}'
Locus3443

Locus555662

Locus800
```

What am I doing wrong here?

thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand this to mean that you want to pick the `Locus` field from the header lines and leave the others unchanged. Then:

```
awk -F _ '/^>/ { print $3; next } 1' filename
```

is perhaps the easiest way. This works as follows:

```
/^>/ {      # in lines that begin with >
  print $3  # print the third field
  next      # and go to the next line.
}
1           # print other lines unchanged. Here 1 means true, and the
            # default action (unchanged printing) is performed.
```

The thing to understand here is awk's control flow: awk code consists of conditions with associated actions, and the actions are performed if the condition evaluates to true.

`/^>/` is a regex match over the whole record (line by default); it is true if the line begins with `>` (because `^` matches the beginning), so

```
/^>/ { print $3; next }
```

will make awk execute `print $3; next` in lines that begin with `>`. The less straightforward part is

```
1
```

which prints lines unchanged. We only get here if the first action was not executed (because of the `next` in it), and this `1` is to be read as a condition that is always true -- nonzero values being true in awk.

Now, if either the condition or the action in an awk statement are omitted, a default is used. The default action is printing the line unchanged, and this takes advantage of it. It would be equally possible to write

```
1 { print }
```

or

```
{ print }
```

In the latter case, the condition is omitted and the default condition "true" is used. `1` is the shortest variant of this and idiomatic because of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F_ '{print (/^>/ ? $3 : $0)}' file
Locus3443
ATTCTACTACTACTCT
Locus555662
CTTCCCTACGATG
Locus800
TTCTACTTCATCT
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a second awk match for the row below. e.g.

```
cat test.fasta | awk -F _ '/^>/ { print $3"_"$4 } /^[A-Z]/ {print $1}'
```

Output:

```
Locus3443_allele1
ATTCTACTACTACTCT
Locus555662_allele2
CTTCCCTACGATG
Locus800_allele0
TTCTACTTCATCT
```

If you don't want the `_allele1` bit remove `"_"$4` from the awk script.

Comment: just saying but in a fasta file you don't want to miss the '>' part of each line

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a regex on each line:

```
$ awk '{ sub(/^.*_L/,"L"); print $0}' /tmp/fasta.txt
Locus3443_allele1
ATTCTACTACTACTCT
Locus555662_allele2
CTTCCCTACGATG
Locus800_allele0
TTCTACTTCATCT
```